# What does the word "while" means in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "It’ll take me a little **while** longer to get ready" ([Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/little)).

What does the word "**while**" means in that sentence?
I'm trying to understand the sentence and I simply couldn't. (I understand that the meaning of "It'll take me a **little**" equals to "It'll take me a **short time**" but the rest isn't clear.

Comment: KIndly, see the sentence here https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/little

Comment: Oh! I got my mistake. My bad. Thank you very much. So basically you answered my question. Please write it as an answer and I'll choose it. I think the way that they explain this word in the dictionary is **misleading** because they say that **little** means **brief time** and give this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A little while" is an idiomatic expression that literally means, "some relatively  short amount of time", e.g.

> I'll see you in **a little while**.

As with many time-related expressions, the actual duration of "a little while" is pretty flexible, ranging anywhere from a few seconds to a few hours (or longer) depending on context:

> The reaction has to run just **a little while** longer ... almost ready ... there!  Pour in the contents of that flask to neutralize the reaction.
>
> Dinner won't be ready for **a little while**, so why don't we watch a movie while we wait?